# Why advection equation is time reversible?

Tags: soft-question

I have advection equation stated in materials provided by professor as follow:

$$
\frac{\delta u}{\delta t} = \nabla \cdot (Vu)
$$

According to [Why heat equation is not time-reversible? (Time arrow in mathematics)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/628720/why-heat-equation-is-not-time-reversible-time-arrow-in-mathematics?newreg=603e07ef8a644cba98740eba5627d70c) I think that equation is not time reversible due to having odd derivative of t. 
But my professor stated that the equation is time reversible.

So my question is as follow:

Is this equation time reversible or not?

Comment: Maybe V also changes under a change $t\rightarrow -t$ if it is a velocity type variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comment, in the [advection equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advection#Mathematics_of_advection) $u$ is a scalar field, as the temperature in the heat equation, but $V$ is a velocity field that change sign when the time $t$ is changed to $-t$.