# Does this system evolve linearly?

Tags: dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system, nonlinear-dynamics, koopman-operator

Say I have discrete-time nonlinear dynamics:

$$ \mathbf{x}_{t+1}=f(\mathbf{x}_t) $$
where $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^d$.

I have an *observable function*, as an example, defined as:

$$ g(\mathbf{x}) = \left[ \cos(\mathbf{w}_0\cdot\mathbf{x}), \ldots, \cos(\mathbf{w}_i\cdot\mathbf{x}),\ldots, \cos(\mathbf{w}_n\cdot\mathbf{x})\right]^\top $$
$$n\rightarrow \infty$$
where $\mathbf{w}_i \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2\mathbf{I}) $. Basically, $g$ maps $\mathbf{x}$ to an infinite dimensional feature vector.

Does the Koopman theory imply that there exists a linear operator $\mathbf{K}$ such that

$$ g(\mathbf{x}_{t+1}) = \mathbf{K} g(\mathbf{x}_t)  $$
?

or does the linear dynamics exist only if I use a $g$ that is specifically constructed for the given nonlinear dynamics $f$, instead of an arbitrary $g$ that I show above as an example? In other words, I am questioning would an arbitrary nonlinear map $g$ make the dynamics linear in the feature space regardless of the given $f$.

Comment: See [this math exchange question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4471490/a-proper-approach-to-learn-koopman-operator-theory) for references. Briefly, as long as the space of observables you construct is sufficiently nice (vector space, complete,...) the op $K$ exists.