# Is a group representation a special case of a group action and can representations be defined on non-vector spaces?

Tags: vector-spaces, representation-theory, group-actions

Is it fair to say that a group representation is a particular case of a group action, in the following sense? We have the definition of group action:

> A left action of a group $G$ on a set $X$ is a homomorphism $\varphi$ from the group $G$ to the group of transformations on $X$, $\varphi: G \to$ Transf($X$).

Then the definition of a group representation on a vector space (is a vector space the most general structure on which a representation is defined?) is given by

> A group representation is a group action on a vector space $V$ for which the image of the action is a subset of the linear transformations on $V$: $\varphi(G) \subset \mathcal{L}(V) \subset$ Transf($V$).

Thus my questions are (1) is this definition of a representation in terms of an action correct and (2) is a vector space the most general structure on which a representation can be defined?

Edit: By group of transformations I mean the group of bijections on $X$; I'm not sure if this terminology is conventional or not.

Comment: This group is the [symmetric group](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Symmetric_group) ${\rm Sym}(X)$.

Comment: Hello, yes you can indeed define a representation as a group action on a vector space respecting the vector space structure. The most general definition of group action/representation would be going through category theory. Constructing the category BG from a group G. And then a "representation" in the category D, is any functor $F: BG\to D$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it fair to say that a group representation is a particular case of a group action, in the following sense? We have the definition of group action:
> A left action of a group $G$ on a set $X$ is a homomorphism $\varphi$ from the group $G$ to the group of transformations on $X$, $\varphi: G \to$ Transf($X$).

Yes; to say the least it would be fair to expect that a representation involves a family of transformations whose parameters satisfy an algebraic relation of sorts.

> Then the definition of a group representation on a vector space (is a vector space the most general structure on which a representation is defined?) is given by
> A group representation is a group action on a vector space $V$ for which the image of the action is a subset of the linear transformations on $V$: $\varphi(G) \subset \mathcal{L}(V) \subset$ Transf($V$).

The answer to this question is somewhat subjective and depends on the context. For some a "representation" of a group is by linear transformations, for some a "representation" is always not merely linear but indeed preserves some additional prespecified structure on the phase space $V$ (e.g. if $V$ has a Hilbert space structure additionally then the representation may be expected to be by unitary linear transformations). On the other end of the spectrum for some a "representation" is an action on a set $X$ by transformations each of which preserves some further prespecified structure on $X$. At times representations in this broader sense are referred to as "non-linear representations".

It should be noted that in any context it is also important to keep in mind what it would mean for two "representations" to be equivalent. See also [How a group represents the passage of time?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/626927/169085) and [Examples of conjugate-like structures across mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4132091/169085) .